# How to properly configure Liquibase in Spring Boot with Maven plugin so that a I can run diff command using latest version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-plugin, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

When I try to execute `liquibase diff` command, I get the following error:

*ERROR [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main]: Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver*

I assume it might have something to do with versions or missing dependencies so here is part of my POM.XML file:

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.4.0</kotlin.version>
        <kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
        <mapstruct.version>1.4.0.Beta3</mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>3.10.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

I've installed liquibase 3.10.2 version - Mac OS and I use postgres. Also, here is part of my liquibase properties file:

````
username=postgres
password=
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.something.something.models?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect```
````

Answer (score 1):

I've switched to version 4.0.0 and updated pom.xml to following:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Now, `mvn liquibase:diff` command generates diff file.